# Vue 2.0 router view doesn't work when used in webpack 2

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I click foo, the console would print as expected, but the `<router-view>` render nothing.

The offical docs only display how to use it in a single html file and javascript code is embeded directly in it. I've read many examples but I can't make it in webpack.

Or is there any example about vue 2 router in webpack?

I create `app.vue` file as a layout:

```
<template>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>

</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

and webpack entry file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
import appView from 'app.vue'

const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' , mounted(){console.log(this,'mount foo')}}
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes 
})

new Vue({
  router,
  render (h) {
      return h(appView);
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='zh'>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<div id="app">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bunlde.js"></script>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why it's not rendering for you. I've got an example project with tutorial that shows you how you can use it in webpack here: https://github.com/prograhammer/example-vue-project

Comment: Any console error? Did you try to inspect your app using the vue dev tools for google chrome?

Comment: @prograhammer @Frank Provost thank you. I finally find out that I must import `vue/dist/vue.esm.js` instead of `vue/dist/vue.js` when using webpack 2.

Answer (score 1):

In case others fall in this trap like me. In your webpack 2 config file, add:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
  }
},
```